# how can i insert this ascii text art in cmd or command prompt?

Tags: cmd, ascii, ascii-art

how can i insert this text art in cmd? Do i do it like this?

```
@echo off
cls
echo .................................................__________......
echo .... _________________________________________ ./           \\___
echo .___/             /..|        /_/   _____   |_ |   _______   ||..
echo .__/ ____       //...|   ____/  |  |.....| ||..|  /...||...\ ||..
echo ../_____/      //....|   || ....|  |_____| ||..|   ___||___  ||..
echo ......./      //.....|   |____..|       ___||..|  |___  ___| ||..
echo ....../      //......|    ___/..|   |\   \\ ...|   ...||...  ||..
echo ...../      //.......|   || ....|   |.\   \\ ..|   ...||...  ||..
echo ..../      //_______ |   |______|_  |..\   \\ .|  \___||___/ ||..
echo .../  ____________ /_|           /  |__.\   \\ |             ||..
echo __/_______________/.\___________/_____/..\___\\\____________//...
pause
```

Comment: Copy/paste not working? What is wrong?

Comment: i create this text art though, and im trying to run it on a cmd, but again after opening the .bat-(batchfile) it closes and nothing happens, it doesnt post anything in the CMD screen.

hope you can help me how to post or echo this text art in cmd. im making a software and i would like to make this as my signature. :)

Comment: so youre saying: cls the "ZERO" ascii art and then, @echo off pause? is that what youre sayin.. hmm.. okay i'll try, thanks for the reply ^^ have a nice day! Godspeed!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this ASCII art is the use of "|" special character.
So no, removing echo off won't help. It's necessary to avoid seeing echo command before each line of your ASCII art. Escaping all pipes will. All you need to do is replace any appearance of: `|` with `^|` and you are good to go.

Just tested and it went fine. Previously it was erroring out each time you had:
`echo ....|...` because it would read: `echo ....` and pipe it to `...` so latter was not found command - pause was never run and whole ASCII was not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

:loop

Set /a num=(%Random% %%9)+1

color %num%

echo .................................................__________......
echo .... _________________________________________ ./           \\___
echo .___/             /..^|        /_/   _____   ^|_ ^|   _______   ^|^|..
echo .__/ ____       //...^|   ____/  ^|  ^|.....^| ^|^|..^|  /...^|^|...\ ^|^|..
echo ../_____/      //....^|   ^|^| ....^|  ^|_____^| ^|^|..^|   ___^|^|___  ^|^|..
echo ......./      //.....^|   ^|____..^|       ___^|^|..^|  ^|___  ___^| ^|^|..
echo ....../      //......^|    ___/..^|   ^|\   \\ ...^|   ...^|^|...  ^|^|..
echo ...../      //.......^|   ^|^| ....^|   ^|.\   \\ ..^|   ...^|^|...  ^|^|..
echo ..../      //_______ ^|   ^|______^|_  ^|..\   \\ .^|  \___^|^|___/ ^|^|..
echo .../  ____________ /_^|           /  ^|__.\   \\ ^|             ^|^|..
echo __/_______________/.\___________/_____/..\___\\\____________//...

pause

goto :loop
```

This should work and flash a random color every time you press a button.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the easiest way would be to save your raw ascii art in a text file (copy/paste it into your editor).

Then, simply `type` out the file:

```
type asciiArt.txt
```

Comment: This is a good idea! You could echo the ASCII Art into `strean1` of the bat file, if you understand what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

pipes ( | )

example:

```
ping google.com | TEST.txt
```

this tells the command (ping google.com) to import the out-put text to TEST.txt
to get around this do " ^| " witch tells your batch file to skip the next character & keep going.

Comment: "import the out-put text to TEST.txt" - actually it tries to execute TEST.txt as a process - which it can't - and pass the output from ping into the TEST.txt process as stdin.

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
title My Name Is Zero
:loop
cls

Set /a num=(%Random% %%9)+1

color %num%

echo .................................................__________......
echo .... _________________________________________ ./           \\___
echo .___/             /..^|        /_/   _____   ^|_ ^|   _______   ^|^|..
echo .__/ ____       //...^|   ____/  ^|  ^|.....^| ^|^|..^|  /...^|^|...\ ^|^|..
echo ../_____/      //....^|   ^|^| ....^|  ^|_____^| ^|^|..^|   ___^|^|___  ^|^|..
echo ......./      //.....^|   ^|____..^|       ___^|^|..^|  ^|___  ___^| ^|^|..
echo ....../      //......^|    ___/..^|   ^|\   \\ ...^|   ...^|^|...  ^|^|..
echo ...../      //.......^|   ^|^| ....^|   ^|.\   \\ ..^|   ...^|^|...  ^|^|..
echo ..../      //_______ ^|   ^|______^|_  ^|..\   \\ .^|  \___^|^|___/ ^|^|..
echo .../  ____________ /_^|           /  ^|__.\   \\ ^|             ^|^|..
echo __/_______________/.\___________/_____/..\___\\\____________//...

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 -w **500** > nul

goto :loop
```